# Ceph s3 bucket permissions policy InvalidArgument

Tags: php, amazon-s3, ceph

I have a Ceph test environment using Jewel version created with an s3 server, what i can see works fine (can add and remove files for buckets)

I been asked to set permissions on the buckets to only allow some users to read a buckets and others can write.

When i use ACL's if one user_a uploads a file, user_b cant read the file even tho user_b has read permissions on the bucket.

I have been on line and looking at the policy part of s3,

When ever i try to set an policy using s3cmd or the s3client php script i get an error message

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><BucketName>test_bucket</BucketName><RequestId>`

and in the s3/radosgw logs i get

2017-11-06 12:54:41.987704 7f67a9feb700  0 failed to parse input:

Can any one explain why i am getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Found it out Ceph Jewel version don't support S3 policy.

They do offer the luminous, version that does offer S3 policys 
well when i updated to Luminous and tired the same command it worked